# What is the use of `nativeWindowOpen` option in webPreferences?

Tags: electron

```
// main.js
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow()

// In this example, only windows with the `about:blank` url will be created.
// All other urls will be blocked.
mainWindow.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler(({ url }) => {
  if (url === 'about:blank') {
    return {
      action: 'allow',
      overrideBrowserWindowOptions: {
        frame: false,
        fullscreenable: false,
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        webPreferences: {
          preload: 'my-child-window-preload-script.js',
          nativeWindowOpen: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return { action: 'deny' }
})
```

[native-window-example](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/window-open#native-window-example)

Getting error without this option

Answer (score 0):

When **nativeWindowOpen** is set to true, the default behavior is enabled, and Electron will create a **new browser window to display the content** of the link when target="_blank" is encountered not render the same window.